# snprintf issue in C

Tags: c, printf, malloc

In the following case, data is not being set as expected and data_handler as well.

```
int main() {

char    *data;
char    *data_handler;
int      i = 0;
int      len , req;
char     test[10] = "test";

for(; i<10; i++){

    req = snprintf(NULL, 0 , "[%s] ", test);

    printf("%d --> req \n", req);
    if (data == NULL) {
        data = (char *) malloc ((sizeof(char) * req) + 1);
        data_handler = data;
    } else {
        data_handler = data + len;
        data_handler = (char *) malloc ((sizeof(char) * req) +1);
    }

    len += snprintf(data_handler, sizeof(data) , "[%s] ", test);

    printf("\nData --> %s\n", data);
    printf("\nData Handler --> %s\n", data_handler);
} 

printf ("%s", data);

}
```

Intention of this program is to append total 10 times test in a string. (Experimenting pointers) but I am getting following output.

```
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> (��

Data Handler --> [te
(��
Exited: ExitFailure 5
```

Comment: `if (data == NULL)` The `data` variable has not been initialised.

Comment: @kaylum Yes, I agree. So I initialized by allocating memory and later pointed that to data_handler.

Comment: But that check will not work as expected because `data` is uninitalised. So you don't know which of the conditional blocks of code it will run. `data` may not be `NULL` the first time as you seem to expect.

Comment: Never cast the return value of `malloc()` in [tag:c].

Comment: Also need `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: `sizeof(data)` is wrong.

Comment: try [this](http://ideone.com/oX18tZ)

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are not automatically initialized,

```
char *data;
```

leaves `data` unuinitialized and that means it has no value stored in it, it's a random value that might be considered garbage and is unpredictable, but it's very likely that it's not `NULL`, so the test is false and you are printing `data` without first initialiazing it.

Also, the `sizeof` operator returns the size of the type and not the allocated size. You should keep the allocated size in order to use it later. The `sizeof` operator gives you the size of an array too but `data` is not an array it's a pointer.

And finally:

1. Do not cast the return value of `malloc()`. [Read here for more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1983495).
2. Don't use `sizeof(char)` because it's `=== 1` by definition.

Comment: Thank you very much.. after making changes you suggested ..It is showing better result but not the one I am expecting..
As per my code I am adding new "test" at the end of the prev string..So at the end it should print " test test test test test .." but it is printing only one "test"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other issues discussed, your code leaks memory badly. You cannot simply continue to `malloc` `data_handler` each iteration. When you do, you overwrite the address of the previously allocated block losing the ability to `free` the previously allocated memory. Instead, you must `realloc` the original block of memory, preserving the pointer `data` pointing to starting address for the block of memory and then update `data_handler` accordingly.
This is a fundamental memory management issue.

Instead, it looks like you were attempting to do the following. I apologize if I misinterpreted your goal, but otherwise your code does not make sense:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    char *data = NULL;
    char *data_handler = NULL;
    int i = 0, len = 0, req = 0;
    char test[10] = "test";

    req = snprintf (NULL, 0, "[%s] ", test);
    printf ("%d --> req\n", req);

    for (; i < 10; i++) {

        if (data == NULL) {
            data = malloc (req + 1);
            data_handler = data;
        }
        else {
            char *tmp = realloc (data, len + req + 1);  /* realloc data */
            if (!tmp) { /* validate */
                fprintf (stderr, "realloc() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            data = tmp;                 /* assign tmp to data  */
            data_handler = data + len;  /* update data_handler */
        }

        len += snprintf (data_handler, sizeof test, "[%s] ", test);

        printf ("-- (len: %d)\nData         --> %s\n", len, data);
        printf ("Data Handler --> %s\n", data_handler);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
    free (data);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/snprintfnoinit
7 --> req
-- (len: 7)
Data         --> [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 14)
Data         --> [test] [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 21)
Data         --> [test] [test] [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 28)
Data         --> [test] [test] [test] [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 35)
Data         --> [test] [test] [test] [test] [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 42)
Data         --> [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 49)
Data         --> [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 56)
Data         --> [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 63)
Data         --> [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 70)
Data         --> [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test] [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a jump on an unintitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. It is simple to use.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/snprintfnoinit
==25279== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25279== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25279== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25279== Command: ./bin/snprintfnoinit
==25279==
7 --> req
-- (len: 7)
Data         --> [test]
Data Handler --> [test]
-- (len: 14)
...
==25279==
==25279== HEAP SUMMARY:
==25279==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==25279==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 395 bytes allocated
==25279==
==25279== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==25279==
==25279== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25279== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Always confirm *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and equally important *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts*.

Look over the changes to the code and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

After adding this include to the code to get it to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

The compiler gives hints as to why the code is not working as expected:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.c
d:\temp\test.c(16) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'data' used
d:\temp\test.c(24) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'len' used
```

**EDIT:**

Below is your code with an include file added so that it compiles and the warnings fixed by initilising the variables as suggested by the compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char    *data=0;
char    *data_handler;
int      i = 0;
int      len=0, req;
char     test[10] = "test";

for(; i<10; i++){

    req = snprintf(NULL, 0 , "[%s] ", test);

    printf("%d --> req \n", req);
    if (data == NULL) {
        data = (char *) malloc ((sizeof(char) * req) + 1);
        data_handler = data;
    } else {
        data_handler = data + len;
        data_handler = (char *) malloc ((sizeof(char) * req) +1);
    }

    len += snprintf(data_handler, sizeof(data) , "[%s] ", test);

    printf("\nData --> %s\n", data);
    printf("\nData Handler --> %s\n", data_handler);
}

printf ("%s", data);

}
```

Here is the output produced by that code:

```
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
7 --> req 

Data --> [te

Data Handler --> [te
[te
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. But casting to `(char *)` certainly hides the error.

Comment: The compiler is pointing out that the `data` variable is undefined as it has not been initialized, as is the `len` variable. Because the `data` variable is undefined it also points out the fact that the if statement 'if (data == NULL) {' at line 16 is not going to work as expected and that is definitely the issue. The other warning is no better as this line of code `len += snprintf` could do anything because `len` is undefined. These warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: Yes 100% with you. And warnings are very helpful for new programmers. I am just teaching it to my sister exactly how important warnings can be.